# Full Memory Usage at python code, with mediapipe library

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, ram, mediapipe

I got a big problem at python code, my code is work correct but my laptop's RAM cant erase unused data, I used 'gc' library but it doesn't any help,
this problem went appear that I change it to class mode.

my code:

```
import cv2 as cv
import mediapipe as mp
import time
import gc

class handDetector():
    def __init__(self, mode=False, maxHands=2, detectionCon=0.5, trackCon=0.5):
        self.mode = mode
        self.maxHands = maxHands
        self.detectionCon = detectionCon
        self.trackCon = trackCon
        self.mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
        self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(self.mode, self.maxHands, 1, self.detectionCon, self.trackCon)
        self.mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
    def findHands(self, image, draw=True):
        imgRGB = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        self.result = self.hands.process(imgRGB)

        if self.result.multi_hand_landmarks:
            for hand in self.result.multi_hand_landmarks:
                if draw:
                    self.mpDraw.draw_landmarks(image, hand, self.mpHands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)
                     cv.FILLED)
        return image
    def findPosition(self, image, handNo=0, draw=True):
        lmList = []
        h, w, c = image.shape
        if self.result.multi_hand_landmarks:
            myHand = self.result.multi_hand_landmarks[handNo]
            for id, land in enumerate(myHand.landmark):
                cx, cy = int(land.x * w), int(land.y * h)
                lmList.append([id, cx, cy])
                if draw:
                    cv.circle(image, (cx,cy), 15, (0,0,255), cv.FILLED)
        return lmList


def main():
    cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
    ret=1   
    pre_time = time.time()
    gc.enable()
    while ret:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        crt_time = time.time()
        fps = int(1/(crt_time-pre_time))
        handDtc = handDetector()
        image = handDtc.findHands(frame)
        lmList = handDtc.findPosition(image) 
        cv.putText(image, str(fps), (50,50), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (255,255,0))        
        image=frame
        cv.imshow('image', image)
        pre_time = time.time()     
        if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            ret = False
            # print(lmList)
        del handDtc
        del image
        gc.collect()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

my RAM storage is 16gb and I have 11gb free, after running the code my RAM will full

Comment: I founded, I have to remove `handDtc = handDetector()` inside the while to the outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to remove `handDtc = handDetector()` inside the while to the outside.
this line make many class object and it will full my RAM.