# Mediapipe hands ML recognition get all of my memory

Tags: python, opencv, mediapipe

I would like to test if the development environment with opencv and the medipipe library works correctly. I tested this code

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp

mp_hands=mp.solutions.hands
mp_drawing=mp.solutions.drawing_utils

webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
while webcam.isOpened():
    success, img = webcam.read()  
    img=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)       results=mp_hands.Hands(max_num_hands=3,min_detection_confidence=0.7,min_tracking_confidence=0.6).process(img)
    cv2.imshow('test', img)
    results=[]
    print("passo")
    if cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
        break
webcam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

but unfortunately the line

```
results=mp_hands.Hands(max_num_hands=3,min_detection_confidence=0.7,min_tracking_confidence=0.6).process(img)
```

once started the program starts to occupy all the gigabytes of RAM on my workstation until it saturates the available RAM.

[Windows Memory Usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWksx.png)

Is it a bug in the library or do I need to fix something in the code?

I'm using Python 3.11 and mediapipe 0.10.5

I've already tried to change the webcam and remove some variables in order to get lower memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

may be you might need to review your code, there are few mistakes like below which leads to heavy memory consumption:

[Full Memory Usage at python code, with mediapipe library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69733880/full-memory-usage-at-python-code-with-mediapipe-library)

https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/2220